# Unable to configure logging in dropwizard. Could not resolve type id 'console'

Tags: gradle, dropwizard

I am trying to configure console appender in my project. It works fine when I launch my app in debug locally. However, when I build it my jar in Gradle and launch it as a standalone app I get following error:

```
[0]; Could not resolve type id 'console' into a subtype of [simple type, class io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory]: known type ids = [AppenderFactory]
```

Here is the snippet of my `.yml` file:

```
logging:
    appenders:
    - type: console
      timeZone: UTC
      logFormat: '%-5level [%date{ISO8601}] [%X{requestId}] %c: %msg%n%rootException'
```

I was able to find posts about similar issues. For instance, this thread [here](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/810) suggests to check if file `META-INF/services/io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory` is in the application jar and if it contents is as following:

```
io.dropwizard.logging.ConsoleAppenderFactory
io.dropwizard.logging.FileAppenderFactory
io.dropwizard.logging.SyslogAppenderFactory
```

I have verified it. In my case file is where it supposed to be and it has exactly the same contents.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Dropwizard version 0.9.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the Gradle produce a Uber/Fat Jar (A jar with all it's dependencies inside itself) or a simple jar with only your Dropwizard app?

It's advisable to build an Fat-jar for Dropwizard deployments, so do switch over to this style if you're not doing so.

Now while building a Fat-Jar, you need to do the following to solve your problem (this was mentioned in the discussion you linked)

> If you use maven-shade plugin for building a fat jar, don't forget about SPI resource transformer for collecting SPI resources into the jar.

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
```

To do the same in Gradle, check this [discussion](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/105).

HTH.

Comment: Yes, it builds a fat jar. What should my internal jar structure be so that Dropwizard knows how to properly read logging config? As I've already mentioned my jar contains META-INF/services/io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory and it conents is as described. What transformations will ServicesResourceTransformer apply? Please clarify.

Comment: Having the ServicesResourceTransformer will merge all possible implementations of a Interface in multiple jars (in their own META-INF files) into one single file. Can you try adding another transformer into your build config? org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer

Comment: I do not understand why I need to invoke shadow plugin in the first place. The thread that I mentioned explains that the issue manifests itself if the structure is not as described. In contrary, in my case my jar contains  META-INF/services/io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory along with above mentioned content. So, the root cause in my case may be completely different. Also, I am no gradle expert..

Comment: Here is how my "fat-jar" is being built:
jar {
    zip64 true
    from { configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    manifest {
        attributes(
        'Main-Class': mainClassName,
        'version': project.version,
        'lastBuild': buildTime()
        )
    }
}
How do I transform jar task above into shadowJar along with transformations that you mentioned?

Comment: Your job will have multiple and/or conflicting META-INF/services files which could have resulted in the error you get. Just because the file is present doesn't mean it got loaded correctly by the JVM. To ensure correct loading, you'll need to use ServicesResourceTransformer to create the right file for your case. Try it out and check if it works.

Comment: You were right, after creating proper gradle build file using shadow jar plugin, I was able to merge all the service files and that issue is gone now!

Comment: @IhorM. Glad to know, Dropwizard with Gradle is not a commonly used together unlike Dropwizard with Maven.